# Создание в Unity partial классов в проекте Editor

Tags: c#, unity3d

В официальной документации сказано что юнити понимает partial классы шарпа. Вот мой пример:

./Assets/Test.cs (находится в основном проекте):

```
namespace Engine {

    public partial class Test : MonoBehaviour {

        [SerializeField]
        private float radius = 1f;

    }

}
```

./Assets/Editor/TestEditor.cs (находится в проекте Editor):

```
namespace Engine {

    public partial class Test {

        private void OnDrawGizmosSelected() {
            Gizmos.color = new Color(1f, 1f, 0f, 0.3f);
            Gizmos.DrawSphere(new Vector3(0,0,0), radius); // в this контексте не видно radius!
        }

    }

}
```

В результате, студия пропускает код, а юнити говорит что переменной radius - не существует. Такое ощущение, что юнити не понимает контекста текущего класса в редакторе. Есть ли способы разделить гизмосы для редактора (отладка) и код релиза по разным классам? Очень не хочется в релизе использовать этот злощастный #if...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Unity` собирает решение из трех отдельных проектов(может и больше, не уверен), один из которых плагины, другой редактор и третий ваш основной. Разделение идет по папкам в которые вы складываете свои файлы (`Plugins`, `Editor` и прочие). Предполагаю что если части класса будут находиться в одном проекте, то все у вас будет работать хорошо, а так получается, что часть класса у вас в проекте редактора, а часть в общем. Полагаю отсюда и проблемы с областью видимости.

Исключительно гипотеза, так что ногами сильно не пинайте)

Comment: Да, это действительно так. К сожалению, не получается отделить код для редактора юнити от кода логики релиза. Спасибо за ответ.